# siunitx: localisation not working

Tags: siunitx

I have just discovered the `siunitx` package and want to use it in a German language document. Unfortunately, I can't get the German word 'bis' instead of 'to' with the `\SIrange` command:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\dot{V}=\SIrange{0}{650}{\litre\per\hour}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``.

Comment: In my (short) experience, it's dangerous to use spacing characters such as `\,`, `\;`, `~`, etc. in the range-phrase, because they can cause range commands to not line break/word wrap and go beyond the right margin. It's better to use just blanks (e.g. `range-phrase={ bis }` instead of `range-phrase={\,bis\,}`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `range-phrase` option, either for the package or the `\SIrange` command. Note that you have to add the spaces before and after `bis`, e.g. using `\,` for 1/2 space.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[range-phrase={\,bis\,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    $\dot{V}=\SIrange{0}{650}{\litre\per\hour}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're going to have lots of similar commands, it might be best to use the `\sisetup` command, rather than passing them all as package options...

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, but according to the documentation this should be done automatically if the `translator' package is present on the system.

Comment: @Alexander: I thought something like this exists. You should mention such things in the main question. I personally prefer to do thing by myself to be sure they work.

Comment: @Alexander: The automated system seems to have a slight flaw, but I'm not sure if that is `siunitx` or `translator`. I'll look at it later today.

Comment: @Joseph: The "flaw" is that translator doesn't know the language as `ngerman` is not a class option. You must either use `ngerman`as class option, or load translator before siunitx with the option ngerman, or activate after siunitx the language `\uselanguage{German}
\languagealias{ngerman}{German}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your comment should be an answer!