# How to use SIrange in math mode

Tags: siunitx

I cannot figure out which of the `siunitx` font options is the correct to typset the  rangephrase when using `SIrange` in math mode the same way as in text mode. See the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{mode=text} % does NOT have an effect here
\begin{document}
\SIrange{1}{2}{\watt}\\
$\alpha=\SIrange{1}{2}{\watt}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also: [siunitx: localisation not working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13493/5645)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not sure why this is not the default behaviour, but if you specify `range-phrase = {\text{~to~}}` you get the same behavior in and out of math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{mode=text,range-phrase = {\text{~to~}}}
\begin{document}
\SIrange{1}{2}{\watt}\\
$\alpha=\SIrange{1}{2}{\watt}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a starting point, but how can one get rid of the italics? Is there any reason why ~to~ is not the default?

Comment: The updated solution uses the `\text` macro to ensure that the `to` is typeset the same way in and outside of math mode. Am sure @Joseph Wright will see this and since he wrote the package he is probably the best to elaborate.

Answer (score 13):

Peter has given an answer to make the range phrase print in text mode, which probably solves the case in point. However, there is a reason that `siunitx` does not do this by default. In particular, in the documentation it states that `\SIrange` should only be used in text mode.

To see why this is, try the following demonstration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
$1\,$m to $10\,$m

Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
\SIrange{1}{10}{\m}

\sisetup{range-phrase = \text{ to }}
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
\SIrange{1}{10}{\m}

\sisetup{range-phrase = \text{ to }\break}
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
Some filler text.
\SIrange{1}{10}{\m}

\end{document}
```

What you'll find is that the use of `\text` here prevents a line break. More importantly, when we force a line break in conjunction with `\text`, the end of the line is wrong. There is no reliable way of setting up an `\ensuretext` macro other than inserting an hbox, and so that is what happens with `\text`. Within such a box, a space which occurs at the end of a line will not be discarded, and so the layout is wrong. Thus while most of the time this looks fine, if the end of the line comes at an inopportune place then disaster will strike. (See for example https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issue/156/unbreakable-space-in-range-phrases where this came up 'in the wild'.) There is no good solution other than stating that `\SIrange` should be used in text mode, and so this is the official position. Hence the standard settings are such that they work correctly in all supported cases.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it sometimes may be desired to have a `SIrange` or `numrange` in math mode. This is also the reason why I stumbled upon this question. In these special and rare cases the answer of Peter Grill will satisfy most, if not all, needs.

**But** in most cases, when you have already "entered" math mode, you'll want to write an **inequality**, as in:

```
$\SI{1}{\watt} \leq \alpha \leq \SI{2}{\watt}$
```

Comment: Arguably, here you'd be better off with ```$1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$\si{\watt}```

Comment: No, definetely not! Don't do this! There are ONLY two correct ways of writing this: Either with the unit on **both** sides *or* with the variable name divided by the unit, f.i. `\alpa / si{W}` to remove dimensions and no units on the numbers.